# POST via php limitation?

Tags: php, html, post

I'm trying to send big multidimentional form via POST and not all elements are getting through.

My post data looks like this:

```
Array
(
[field1] => Array
    (
        [{i}] => Array
            (
                [mail_id] => {id}
                [email] => {mail}
                [sel] => {sel}
            )
        [{i}] => Array
            (
                [mail_id] => {id}
                [email] => {mail}
                [sel] => {sel}
            )
}
```

There are up to 300 elements in filed1 and I want more.
But I can't send more:/
Changing post_max_size does'nt help.
Is there another limitation for multidimentional post?

Comment: Json encode the form to get past the limitation.

Comment: You might want to consider breaking this up to smaller segments in case there is any kind of user involvement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change php.ini:

```
max_input_vars = 5000 #Eg.
```

save, and restart Server